# PJSUA transfer call not working in python37 how ever it is working in python27

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pjsip, pjsua2

current_call.transfer("sip:1001@xx.xx.xx.xx") is working python2.7 How ever it is not working in python3.7
below is the error

```
Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trycall.py", line 151, in <module>
    current_call.transfer("sip:1001@xx.xx.xx.xx")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pjsua.py", line 1734, in transfer
    Lib._create_msg_data(hdr_list))
SystemError: <built-in function call_xfer> returned NULL without setting an error
```

Comment: Hi Dev Jalla, did you resolved this issue, I'm facing same problem, it took too much time but issue was not resolved.

Comment: we achieved this via asterisk ami, python 3 was not supported, if you working on similar project, please let me know.

Comment: Do you use ettoreleandrotognoli/python-ami? I dont find transfer call in that library, if dont have solution, I will continue with pjsua python2

Answer (score 0):

I am using this branch of PJSIP: [Link](https://github.com/malarinv/pjproject/tree/py37)
for PJSUA implementation with Python 3.6 and have encountered same problem with transfer.

Removing this check from function *py_pjsua_call_xfer* (pjproject/pjsip-apps/src/python/_pjsua.c) solved my problem:

```
if (!PyBytes_Check(pDstUri))
    return NULL;
```

This check always returns NULL in all my tests. I was not able to solved this with Python. Removing code mentioned above solved the issue and for now it haven't created any new problems. I have tested this modification with Asterisk and 3 SIP endpoints and transfer was correctly processed.

(note: I am not a C/C++ programmer, so I cannot provide detail explenation why this code doesn't work. This approach is based on trial and error.)